# Filter content in .xls with .vbs

Tags: excel, batch-file, vbscript

I have an .xls file (sheet 1), where there is an x amount of rows and a set amount of columns (always 9), of which the 6th column has to be filtered on a specific partial string ("Hello" has to be displayed when filtered on both "hello" and/or "ell"). This data then has to be copied into worksheet 2 of another .xls (sheet 2). I've set up a template in which the current format of the schedule can be set (worksheet 2 of sheet 2), which will then convert it into the new format (worksheet 1 of sheet 2). I have no knowledge of .vbs at all, but when I did some research on how to make this as automatic as possible, I got the advice to have a .bat file request a .vbs file, which made it easy to alter the excel content. I've tried to find out how to work with the .vbs script, but most of the .vbs used to alter .xls files is the 'easier' tasks, as renaming a worksheet. If anyone can just point me in the right direction, that would be amazing.

Edit:
This is what I have so far

```
'launch Excel and open file
 Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set xlFile = xlObj.WorkBooks.Open("C:\test.xls")
'turn off screen alerts
 xlObj.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$F$2:$F$200").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FilterData, Operator:=xlFilterValue

Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(.xlUp).Row
set Source = Range("A2:P" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Source.Copy

Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlFile = xlObj.WorkBooks.Open("C:\test2.xls")
'turn off screen alerts
xlObj.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

set Dest = Range("A1")
Dest.Paste
Next
xlFile.Close true
xlObj.Quit

Next  
'save, close, then quit
xlFile.Close true
xlObj.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

This page should contain everything you need.
http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/msoffice/excel/

I'd use a Do Until loop to work through each row of the worksheet.  This will make sure that it can dynamically adjust to the number of rows instead of being changed each time.  I'd then use a Do Until loop to read and record the data in each cell for each column of a row.  Again, this makes it so the code can dynamically adjust for size in the future.  Just copy the value of the cell into a variable which you can then use to copy wherever you like.  The link I posted contains all the syntax you'll need.

BTW,
Cell coordinates in vbScript don't use letters.  They use two integers and IIRC they go (Y,X).

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a piece of advice: use [JScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yek4tbz0(v=vs.84).aspx) instead VBS. The two languages are very similar, so you may translate any VBS segment to JScript immediately. However, if the idea is to use VBS/JScript *just as interface* to the Excell sheet and perform the data processing in a Batch file, then JScript have advantages because it is very easy to keep all the code in just one Batch-JScript hybrid script. For example, the code below show the contents of the spreadsheet given as parameter of the Batch file:

```
@if (@CodeSegment == @Batch) @then


@echo off
cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" %1
goto :EOF


@end


var objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application"),
    objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(WScript.Arguments(0));

for ( var row = 1; objExcel.Cells(row,1).Value; ++row ) {
   var line = "";
   for ( var col = 1; objExcel.Cells(row,col).Value; ++col ) {
      line += '"' + objExcel.Cells(row,col).Value + '" ';
   }
   WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(line);
}
objExcel.Quit();
```

This way, you may process such data in the Batch code in any way you wish, so you need to learn just the minimum of JScript (or VBS for that matter). For example, to process just the column 6 looking for "Hello" word:

```
@if (@CodeSegment == @Batch) @then


@echo off

for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" theSheet.xls') do (
   if "%%b" equ "Hello" echo "Hello" word found in row %%a
)
goto :EOF


@end


var objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application"),
    objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(WScript.Arguments(0));

for ( var row = 1; objExcel.Cells(row,6).Value; ++row ) {
   WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(row + ":" + objExcel.Cells(row,6).Value);
}
objExcel.Quit();
```